# stop a div tag from refreshing an image

Tags: html, css

I am using a div to make a cover image. Somehow this div tag takes time to load an image or refreshes an image. If I use an img tag, the cover image renders straightforward, i.e., the image is already displayed  when the page is loaded.

In a div tag,

```
<div class="cover-img"></div>

.cover-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(cover.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The image is being loaded after the page is loaded, so it looks like refreshing.

```
<img class="cover-img" src="cover.png">
.cover-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In this case, the image has already been rendered when the page is loaded, so it looks fine.

I hope this makes sense, and don't get why this behaves differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you should do to load your image faster.

1. Start by resizing your image. The larger the image and the size the slower it is to load.
2. optimize your image formate. `JPG` and `jpeg` one of the most common image formats being used currently on the web and are each suited for different use cases.
3. **Load fewer resources** by that I mean using the `loading="lazy"` to load other images on your website can help the browser to focus on loading your image faster.
4. You could also use `CDN` for your image link.
5. Compressing your image helps a lot. Use tools like [tinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) The ideal size for an image should be less than 1MB the less the size the faster the load is.
6. You can also use the `loading=" eager"` attribute to load the image faster [learn more about loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-loading)

Lastly, everything I said can help you out but in the end, it will depend on the user's connection and how well the user device can handle it.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title>Refresh Image</title> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <!-- Display the image --> 
    <img id="gfgimage" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" 
        height="100" width="auto" /> 
  
    <script> 
        // Create a timestamp 
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime(); 
  
        // Get the image element  
        var image = document.getElementById("gfgimage"); 
  
        // Adding the timestamp parameter to image src 
        image.src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?t=" + timestamp; 
        console.log(image.src); 
    </script> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```

Please add script code like this.

Comment: Can you give an explanation of what you have changed?

Comment: I have add an Id in image tag and write the script.